# Ionic and npm permission

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I've setup a ionic v1 project.
Now when i type the following command:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for ios

    Error: Failed to fetch platform ios
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is 
    incorrect.
    Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
    Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 194 Error output:
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to 
    /Users/tom/Documents/node_modules/ios
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    '/Users/tom/Documents/package.json'
    npm WARN Documents No description
    npm WARN Documents No repository field.
    npm WARN Documents No README data
    npm WARN Documents No license field.

    npm ERR! path /Users/tom/Documents/node_modules/ios
    npm ERR! code ELOOP
    npm ERR! errno -62
    npm ERR! syscall access
    npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access 
    '/Users/tom/Documents/node_modules/ios'
```

how can i resolve this error?